# Targeting older macOS versions using Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

What is the earliest macOS version that an app developed using Swift 4 (Xcode 9) will work on?

Comment: Easy to find out: Set the deployment target in Xcode to 10.6, then build and read the error message ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you're asking. You might be able to run Swift 4 itself (that is, the toolchain) on older macOS versions for non-Xcode development.

If you're asking what's the oldest deployment target, the oldest macOS that Swift-compiled apps will run on, the answer is here:

```
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html
```

That is, Swift can deploy back to macOS 10.9.

If you're asking what's the oldest macOS to run Swift 4 within Xcode, you need Xcode 9, which needs to run on 10.12.4+, which forces you to SDK 10.13+.